# Callback after document conversion

Tags: google-drive-api

When uploading a document to google drive through SDK, it's possible to [convert it and to ocr it](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert).

Two questions:

- is there any callback to let us know the conversion is done?
- is there any way to only retrieve the text from the converted document?

  (I mean without downloading the doc, just get the text directly)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily convert many document formats using [Groupdocs conversions app](http://groupdocs.com/apps/conversion)

I hope it helps.